# Refactor code to make database calls instead of using local storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, auth0

The code below handles authentication for a Vue.js application. It stores and retrives some important values in local storage. How do I refactor this code so as to get and set the values `expiresAt`, `idToken`,  `accessToken` and `user` from memory instead of local storage?

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js'
import Vue from 'vue'

let webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
domain: 'your_auth0_domain',
clientID: 'your_auth0_client',

redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/callback',

audience: 'https://' + 'your_auth0_domain' + '/api/v2/',
responseType: 'token id_token',
scope: 'openid profile' // define the scopes you want to use
})

let auth = new Vue({
computed: {
    token: {
        get: function () {
            return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
        },
        set: function (id_token) {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token)
        }
    },
    accessToken: {
        get: function () {
            return localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        },
        set: function (accessToken) {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken)
        }
    },
    expiresAt: {
        get: function () {
            return localStorage.getItem('expires_at')
        },
        set: function (expiresIn) {
            let expiresAt = JSON.stringify(expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime())
            localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt)
        }
    },
    user: {
        get: function () {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        },
        set: function (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    login() {
        webAuth.authorize()
    },
    logout() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('expires_at')
            localStorage.removeItem('user')
            webAuth.authorize()

        })
    },
    isAuthenticated() {
        return new Date().getTime() < this.expiresAt
    },
    handleAuthentication() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            webAuth.parseHash((err, authResult) => {

                if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
                    this.expiresAt = authResult.expiresIn
                    this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken
                    this.token = authResult.idToken
                    this.user = authResult.idTokenPayload

                    resolve()


                } else if (err) {
                    this.logout()
                    reject(err)
                }

            })
        })
    }
}
})

export default {
install: function (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$auth = auth
}
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean to 'memory' instead of localstorage? This code, is authenticating your user on the client side using OIDC which is meant for client side, that is why it is storing it in local storage on the client side, if you want you change this to server side then don't use OIDC

Comment: the title says "using a database", the question says "in memory". Which is it? Please be clear. In-memory doesn't make much sense tbh, how does the data get into memory in order to be compared against in the first place? If you want to use a database, if you plan to host it yourself you'll need a server-side language as well (you can't talk to the DB direct using JavaScript), and even if you use a hosted DB (e.g. Azure or something) you'll need to learn how to use AJAX requests. Your question is too broad, and too vague - there could be many implementations depending on design choices.

Comment: Please pardon the error on the title I will see if I can edit the question. What I want to achieve is to avoid using local storage.

Comment: Ok but that's still a bit vague. What problem is localstorage giving you that you wish you avoid? (I assume there's a problem, otherwise you wouldn't want to change it). What requirement do you have instead, to improve your application? If you want to use a traditional database instead, I've already told you what your options are.

Comment: The requirement I have is to avoid local storage and refactor the code to something to what is found here [link](https://auth0.com/blog/react-tutorial-building-and-securing-your-first-app) However this was implemented in React. How can I achieve the same thing with Vue?

Comment: To do it directly to reproduce that example? By re-writing the code using vue's syntax in place of the relevant react components. But that's too big a job to ask people to do here. However...rather than worrying about examples written in react, you more just need to replace your current calls to localstorage with ajax requests to your server, which will then call the database. There are lots of ways to write ajax requests...using native XHR, or Axios (which you've tagged) or other plugins. Choose a syntax which suits you.

Comment: Do some research, make a start, and if you actually get stuck on a specific issue that would be a good time to ask question here. We're not going to write everything for you, and we're not going to make you a generic tutorial, and we're not going to explain the concepts of AJAX, because you can already learn that elsewhere (and by studying previous questions on this site, if it comes to that). What we will do is help you with your attempt to re-implement your solution, if any when you get stuck on something particular within it. Thanks.